# Android: Get video from Gallery uri

Tags: android, video, android-intent, android-gallery

I'm trying to get a video from the Android Gallery and get the full path, so I can upload the video in an app...

I'm displaying the gallery like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("video/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, context.getResources().getString(R.string.popup_menu_share_video_title)), Const.PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST);
```

I then extract the uri:

```
Uri selectedUri = data.getData();
String selectedPath = getRealPathFromURI(this, selectedUri);
```

And attempt to get the path:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't seem the get the path...

I can see all the videos if I do this:

```
public static void dumpVideos(Context context ) {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int vidsCount = 0;
    if (c != null) {
        vidsCount = c.getCount();
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("VIDEO", c.getString(0));
        }
        c.close();
    }
    Log.d("VIDEO", "Total count of videos: " + vidsCount);
}
```

So I'm thinking there must be some real simple step, that I'm missing...

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to get a video from the Android Gallery

First, there is no "Android Gallery". There are many apps that might be considered "gallery" apps. There are thousands of device models, and they will ship with a wide variety of "gallery" apps, in addition to those that the user installs.

Second, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is not somehow magically limited to "gallery" apps. Any app can elect to support `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` for `video/*`.

> and get the full path

That is impossible. You have no way of knowing what app the user chooses to handle your `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` request. You have no way of knowing what sort of `Uri` you will get back. You have no way of knowing where the content identified by that `Uri` will be stored, as it does not have to be a file on the filesystem that you can access.

> so I can upload the video in an app

Use `openInputStream()` on `ContentResolver` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. Then, either:

- Use that stream directly with your preferred HTTP client API to upload the content, or
- Use that stream to make a local file copy of the content, then use that file with your preferred HTTP client

> And attempt to get the path:

At best, that code will work in very limited circumstances:

- The app that the user chooses to handle your `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` request happens to return a `content` `Uri` from the `MediaStore`
- That content happens to be on external storage, not removable storage

Since that will not cover all of your scenarios, get rid of that code.

> I can see all the videos if I do this

No, you can get *paths* for *some* videos:

- Not every video accessible via `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` will be known to the `MediaStore`
- Not every video in the `MediaStore` will be on external storage, where you might be able to access it via filesystem APIs

Comment: While I appreciate the elaborate explanations, none of these are suggested solutions to what I'm trying to accomplish. The uploading of the video is already working, as I'm already doing that with videos that the user records directly in the app. I simply need to be able to get a video from the device as well. And all the proposed solutions I've seen on both Stackoverflow and various blogs seems to propose what I'm already doing, yet, I can't seem to get a hold of the video from the uri...

Comment: @user969043: "I simply need to be able to get a video from the device as well" -- follow the instructions from my answer, in the portion starting with "Use `openInputStream()`...". Or, if you want to work exclusively with files, stop using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, and instead use a file-browsing library. "And all the proposed solutions I've seen on both Stackoverflow and various blogs seems to propose what I'm already doing" -- they are wrong. You cannot assume that a `Uri` from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is something that the `MediaStore` knows about, plain and simple.

Answer (score 2):

you can solve this issue by using ACTION_PICK instead of ACTION_GET_CONTENT. I believe unless you need the functionality of adding pictures/videos from Dropbox etc. it's not worth it.If all you need is to get stuff from the gallery use this code:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
           final Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
           photoPickerIntent.setType("image/* video/*");
           startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PICK_PHOTO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
 } else {
           final Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
           photoPickerIntent.setType("*/*");
           photoPickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[]{"image/*", "video/*"});
           startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PICK_PHOTO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
 }
```

I just tried the code you posted with ACTION_PICK and it works perfectly!